# How can I change a svn external in the repository

Tags: svn, svn-externals

We have a number of externals in our project and I wish to create an additional branch within them.

I have gone in and modified the svn:external properties on my local copy and all is good there and have attempted to commit these to the repository (doing an svn ci -m "external", I also tried svn ci --depth empty -m "external") but when another user updates their dev, they still have the old external reference.

Doing an SVN export also returns the old external.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you first commit your property change (ie the `svn:external` property change), then `svn update`, and only then made changes and commit those?

Comment: Yes (using the commands stated above). I haven't done any changes in any other files at this stage (I want to make sure that the external changes are committed first).

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight, 
you have an svn external:
something http://example.com/something/tag/1.2

and you want to change it to 
something http://example.com/something/branch/1.2

then you need to 
1.edit the svn externals which you have already done, 
2. do an svn up (if you cant svn up then you might need to delete the branch you already have in your repo)
4. then you will be able to check in the new branch..

best
Jeff

Comment: If I did a property change, then commit, then update, then commit (yes I played a lot), should that have worked?